# Recover DigitalProductId after Windows Upgrade

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, registry, licensing

Hi we created a Software which uses

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId
```

as a part of an encryption key for a local database. The problem is that when the users upgrade from

```
win8->win10, 
win8->win8.1 
....
```

this key changes and we cannot decrypt the local database anymore.

Is it possible to read the previous value or get an event before windows is upgraded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found something here

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Source OS (Updated on 8/1/2015 02:45:41)`

but seems to work only for upgrades to win10